# Why does accessing a reactive variable not work in my Vue-app (trying to implement a dark mode in Vue)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, darkmode

I am implementing a dark mode for my Vue-app. I was able to make it switch between light- and dark-mode by adding a class attribute for dark-mode and removing it using [State Management](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#what-is-state-management). See this code snippet in `toggleTheme.ts`:

```
import {reactive} from "vue";

export const themeSwitch = reactive({
  dark: false,
  toggleTheme() {
    this.dark = !this.dark;
    console.log("dark in toggleTheme: " + this.dark);
    this.manipulateClass();
  },
  manipulateClass() {
    console.log("dark in manipulateClass: " + this.dark);
    if (this.dark) {
      document.documentElement.className = theme;
    } else {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove(theme);
    }
  }
})
```

And it's usage in my NavBarLoggedIn-Component. Simplified, here it is:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { themeSwitch } from '../composables/toggleTheme.ts'

</script>

<template>
  <nav>
     <button @click="themeSwitch.toggleTheme()">
  </nav>
</template>
```

Now, I wanted to access the value of my dark-reactive on each page load using [mounted](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html) and change the Theme accordingly. For that, I added this snippet into the script-tag of my App.vue-file:

```
import {onMounted} from "vue";
import { themeSwitch } from "@/composables/toggleTheme";

onMounted(() => {
  console.log("dark: " + themeSwitch.dark);
  themeSwitch.manipulateClass();
})
```

The method `onMounted` is called as expected, however, the value of `dark` is always false when I go to another page and call it. Why is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Explaining it, I have found the reason. It was because I always entered the corresponding page into the URL of my browser. `/register` vs. `/home` ... when clicking on a `RouterLink`, for example:

```
<RouterLink to="/register">Register</RouterLink>
```

It worked, the app remembered the correct value. :/ Stupid me.